# A TV show involving brains being sucked out and launched into space

Tags: story-identification, tv

Some years ago, I watched a series on Swedish television. I remember the show was NOT Swedish, but from the UK (maybe USA?).

I only remember one episode specifically and I can't get it out of my head.

It was a show about kids/teens and science. The episode I remember has a science person (not sure if it was a teen or adult) create a machine that can suck peoples' brains out with a tube and launch the brain (in this case, into an aquarium).

I remember it showing two perspectives. One perspective was from two brains that got launched and somehow ended up outside. They could talk and move (by bouncing around), and it was a girl and a boy. The other perspective was the science person using their bodies and turning them into remote controlled people through special hats.

I remember it ending with the a show and tell, where two kids had used the machine on their friend and put his brain in a jar and they showed the remote controlled body as a presentation.

Comment: 'and I can't get it out of my head.' pun intended?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found this TV show, [Round the Twist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Round_the_Twist_episodes). Series 3 episode 8, "[Brainless](http://roundthetwist.wikia.com/wiki/Brainless)" matches pretty well with your description.

> Bronson and Anthony's science project goes spectacularly wrong, sucking Pete and Linda's brains right out of their heads. With their brainless bodies running away, trying to reunite them with their brains isn't easy, especially when James and his friends start to interfere. Linda falls for Anthony after he reads from the Viking Book of Love.

This episode is available on YouTube :

Comment: That...is just kind of wrong...

Comment: @JohnP The answer or the video ? Cause I survived 4 minutes watching that thing

Comment: Just the concept. I was not brave enough to try the video.

Comment: But entirely appropriate considering "round the twist" is a UKism for going insane.

Comment: Thank you so much! Glad to know my childhood feeling of horror and dread watching this is still around. Watched all of it and feel sick. Wow.

Comment: Round the Twist was an Australian show, of course.

Comment: I first watched Round The Twist immediately after seeing Evil Dead for the first time. Guess which one kept me awake the rest of the night, go on.

Comment: Round the Twist is based on a series of children's books and short stories by [Paul Jennings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Jennings_(Australian_author)). They're kinda the Australian equivalent to 'Goosebumps', but less focus on the 'scary' and more on the weird.